# best practice for calling api request in action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm just wondering if it's okay to separate API request in action?

```
export const fetchAllData = () => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
      axios
      .get('')
      .then(res => 
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_DATA", data: res.data })
      )
      .catch(err => 
        dispatch({ type: "ERROR",msg: "Unable to fetch data" })
      );
    };
}
```

I'm thiking maybe just do a request in api folder and import it in aciton? Is the right thing to do or just overkill?

```
import apiFect from '../api';

export const fetchAllData = () => {

apiFetch();

}
```

Comment: What does `apiFetch()` return?

Comment: basicall I'm calling the api request only insted of calling directly in the actions @Nick I just want to seperate only the file of api request and file of actions

Comment: Then don't you lose the ability to dispatch actions asynchronously, or is `apiFetch()` returning a thunk?

Comment: yap I try it haha I must return plain object that's the error lol. Is there a better way to do it? @Nick

Comment: Your initial way of returning a thunk is the way I'm used to seeing it

Comment: redux saga is the same right? I check it right now seems like they both the same in terms of on how you call api request in action. Hmm okay thanks I just feel like there some better way to do it. Well if aint broke dont fix it. thanks anyway. @Nick

Comment: @RoelJohn You're right that it's better to not call axios (or any other http client that is used) directly. The redux action only needs a promise that wait on. The api client module usually does some things on a lower abstraction level, like transforming responses, setting request headers etc., that you don't want to deal with in the action creator. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice example below:

```
// api.js
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: '...',
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

// You can do more stuff here like intercepting responses, etc.
// that is of no concern to the redux actions.
export const getThing = (id) => client.get(`/things/${id}`);


// actions.js
import { getThing } from 'api';

export const fetchAllData = (id) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        getThing(id)
            .then(res => dispatch({ type: "FETCH_DATA", data: res.data }))
            .catch(err => dispatch({ type: "ERROR", msg: "Unable to fetch data" }));
    };
}
```